# feature request: make numbered list formatting less math unfriendly

Tags: feature-request, markdown, list

As explained in [this other post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36203), numbered list formatting can be quite math unfriendly. Would it be possible to use a new numbered list, used on circles, squared or "bracketed" numbers, as shown in the post?

Hereby the same example, as mentioned in that other post: what are the roots of the equation `x^2-3x+2=0`? Hereby the answers:

1. 1
2. 2

Is this to be read as (`1` and `2`) or as (`1 times 1` and `2 times 2`)?

A small extra question: it seems not be possible to use MathJax formatting on this site, which hinders asking questions about math-site related subjects.
Is it feasible to support all formattings from all StackExchange sites here?

Comment: I think they already explained or told you that MathJax does not support the list or enumerate environments and I don't think all sites are interested in your new way of numbering. and it's certainly not about mathjax it's about markdown.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover This isn't about MathJax.  It is about Markdown.  The discussion of MathJax is a red herring.

Comment: Put what is needed to ask in this post, not in another post. Also it is clear from the last comment that that post is still not clear anyway.

Comment: I think that the proposal or your idea, if you consider that it affects you so much, can be resolved via third parties... a plugin or something like that... but I don't see that the community is showing interest in improving this. since it escapes the scope of markdown.

Comment: I think this is clear enough and fits the scope here, voted to reopen. (Do note, this has nothing to do with the question score; Feature request can be not popular hence have negative score but still valid and might actually be done one day.)

Comment: Voted down and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this really necessary? The difference between

1. 1

and

1 · 1

is (at least to me) quite obvious: above, the dot is shifted to the left (so it belongs to the first 1) and it has the same baseline as the numbers, so it's not a multiplication symbol, which is always centered (both horizontally and vertically).

Furthermore, when using MathJax (not supported here on Meta.SE), numbers are in a different font than regular text:

[image]

which makes it even more obvious it's a not calculation, unlike

[image]

The dot has been the ubiquitous indicator for [ordered lists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) for ages, and you need some advanced CSS to change it: [Ordered list (HTML) lower-alpha with right parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1632005/4751173) You might be able to turn one of the answers there to a custom stylesheet which you can add to your browser: [How can I force my css styles when I visit a website?](https://superuser.com/q/560539/442468)

Comment: I don't see it as something really necessary, but in order to implement this, I believe a split should be made in markdown features between the different StackExchange sites. And maybe this might open doors to more (even better) markdown differences.